# Why does Access change the Range in doCmd.TransferSpreadsheet?

Tags: vba, ms-access, import

I am trying to automate importing various ranges in various copies of the same Excel workbook into Access.

The relevant line of code that's causing the error is:

```
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ApplicationLevelSummary_In", "C:\Users\gfunk\Desktop\unserved2.xlsx", True, "'BPO Use Only'!A3:Z11"
```

The error is:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object ''BPO Use Only'$A3:Z11'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If ''BPO Use Only'$A3:Z11' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

As you can see, it's removing the exclamation point after the worksheet name and doing some funky things with the quotes. What's going on here?

I can't rename the sheets in the workbook, as they've already been distributed to people who will fill them out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it didn't like the single quotes or the dollar signs in the ranges. Once I removed them and passed the entire string as a flat string, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx)

> A string expression that's a valid range of cells or the name of a range in the spreadsheet. This argument applies only to importing. Leave this argument blank to import the entire spreadsheet. When you export to a spreadsheet, you must leave this argument blank. If you enter a range, the export will fail.

If you did just

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ApplicationLevelSummary_In", "C:\Users\gfunk\Desktop\unserved2.xlsx", True
```

and `C:\Users\gfunk\Desktop\unserved2.xlsx` already exists, then it will be put into A1 of a new worksheet called `ApplicationLevelSummary_In`

If you need your data to go to a specific range I'd suggest using COM automation instead. It is still fast but it's no one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer to this troubling issue.  I had the same issue with Access replacing the "!" character with a "$" in a range string that I passed to the Range:= parameter of the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet routine.  Finally, I tried to separate the worksheet name and the address range into two different strings, concatenating them with a "!", as in:

```
strSheetName = "MySheet"
strRange = "A1:Q789"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
  TransferType:=acImport, _
  SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
  TableName:="tblImport", _
  FileName:=strFilename, _
  HasFieldNames:=True, _
  Range:=strSheetName & "!" & strRange
```

I had success in convincing Access to import the sheet and the range I wanted it to, instead of allowing it to replace the "!" with a "$".

Hope this helps you as it did me.