# Importing data from Excel range to Access while creating table on the fly

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to transfer/paste data from an Excel range to an Access database creating a table along the way.

I tried the `TransferSpreadsheet` method but it has known bugs. It works on some ranges in the spreadsheet but not on others.

I tried multiple ways to recreate the range string but Access fails to detect the range object.
[Access VBA not recognizing range in Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297134/access-vba-not-recognizing-range-in-excel-spreadsheet)
[Why does Access change the Range in doCmd.TransferSpreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368414/why-does-access-change-the-range-in-docmd-transferspreadsheet?rq=1)

I believe there would be some way to execute a query using the DAO Interface/Db.Execute but not sure how I would create a table and read the field names/field types from the Excel range in the same query.

```vb
Public Sub pushTable(tablename As String, dbName As String)

    Dim acc As Object
    Dim db As Object
    
    Set acc = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    acc.OpenCurrentDatabase dbName & ".accdb"
    
    Dim ref_range As Variant
    ref_range = ActiveWorkbook.Names(tablename).Value
    
    Dim sheet_name As Variant
    sheet_name = Replace(Left(ref_range, InStr(ref_range, "$") - 2), "=", "")
    sheet_name = CStr(Replace(sheet_name, "=", ""))
    
    Dim add As String
    add = Replace(ref_range, "$", "")
    add = CStr(Right(add, Len(add) - InStr(add, "!")))
    
    Dim first As String
    Dim second As String
    first = Split(add, ":")(0)
    second = Split(add, ":")(1)
    
    Dim range_str As Variant
    range_str = sheet_name & "!" & first & ":" & second
    
    acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=0, _
            SpreadSheetType:=10, _
            tablename:=tablename, _
            Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            Range:=range_str
            
    Debug.Print tablename & " created"
    Debug.Print "Closing DataBase Connection"
        
    acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
    acc.Quit
    
    Set acc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Data Layout
[image: Data Layout]

Comment: Data should be provided as formatted text table, not image https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support. Check out this source http://accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm